# WCF Service parse JSON as Dictionary<string,string>()

Tags: c#, json, ajax, wcf

I have a whole load of WCF web services that receive POST JSON objects and reply with other JSON formatted data.

In one particular method within a service I'm trying to pass a JSON object through and parse it as a Dictionary().

The interface to the method is defined as:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "GetSomeData")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string GetSomeData(AuthenticationData authData, Dictionary<string, string> options, string srcHash);
```

and the method declaration itself is:

```
public string GetSomeData(AuthenticationData authData, Dictionary<string,string> options, string srcHash)
{
    // do something fancy
}
```

the authData, and srcHash are standard parameters on all the methods and contain the expected data, correctly parsed as an AuthenticationData object for authData.

Other methods work perfectly fine for both declared objects and primitives however the Dictionary is always empty.

The JSON string being sent through is:

```
"{\"options\",{\"id\":\"1\"}}"
```

Why is this not being parsed as a Dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up on this and created a List class to simulate a dictionary.

```
[Serializable]
public class JSONDictionary
{
    [DataMember] public string _key;
    [DataMember] public string _value;
}
```

Then on the client side (Javascript):

```
client.utils.toJSONDictionary = function (obj)
{
    var dictionary = [];
    for (member in obj)
    {
        dictionary.push({ _key: member, _value: obj[member].toString() });
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

And that works fine. Would be nice to use a proper dictionary in c# but... well you can't have everything.